# Xcode 4 stack trace debugging issue

Tags: xcode4

For a while now (I can't remember exactly which version) Xcode 4 has not been working properly. In that whenever my code crashes the debugger just shows me the main() function and there is a stack trace like this:

```
#0  0x9018b9c6 in __pthread_kill ()
#1  0x90105f78 in pthread_kill ()
#2  0x900f6bdd in abort ()
#3  0x03c93e78 in dyld_stub__Unwind_DeleteException ()
#4  0x03c9189e in default_terminate() ()
#5  0x0154df4b in _objc_terminate ()
#6  0x03c918de in safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) ()
#7  0x03c91946 in __cxa_bad_typeid ()
#8  0x03c92b3e in __cxa_current_exception_type ()
#9  0x0154de49 in objc_exception_rethrow ()
#10 0x012f2e10 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#11 0x012f2ccb in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#12 0x012a5879 in GSEventRunModal ()
#13 0x012a593e in GSEventRun ()
#14 0x00013a9b in UIApplicationMain ()
#15 0x00002a02 in main at /Users/dan/Dev/Container/Container/main.m:16
```

In the console I get some more meaningful information, in this case it tells me:

```
2011-11-09 10:39:53.886 Container[27273:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

In this example I know what the problem is because I made the error (I'm trying to access an object in an empty NSArray) on purpose to try and get to the bottom of this issue. However, I can't figure out what is going wrong. I've lived with it up until now as lot of the bugs I've had I've been familiar with and knew where to look anyway but still, it's becoming a real pain.

Can anyone please shed some light on this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to stop at the point in code when the exception actually occurs, not when it has been bubbled up to your main method. To do so, set an exception breakpoint as explained here: [Exception Breakpoint in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode)

Comment: Thanks for your timely response, now I can get finish my debugging. ;-)

Comment: Although it might not help you anymore it might help the next one finding this question. ;-)