# How to add Exception Breakpoint in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

How to add Exception Breakpoint in Xcode?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppController");
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

My Project randomly crashed in below code, searched in google and some one suggested to add Exception Breakpoint. I added break point by clicking on source line..Editing breakpoint not allow me to change type. How to add Exception Breakpoint and where to add? (in AppDelegate?

[image]

Comment: it doesn't crash in given code.

Comment: @rptwsthi, yup, after adding exception-breakpoint-in-xcode I got exact line of crash. Its great..why not apple by default enable this in debug mode...:)

Comment: @iPhoneChip: Probably because it just stops there and doesn't provide the information about the exception.

Answer (score 72):

You can easily add Exception Breakpoint in Xcode. See below image:

[image]

Answer (score 28):

Here are the steps.

- Move to "Breakpoint Navigator".
- Click + symbol at bottom-left corner of navigator.

[image]

- You should see this.

[image]

Answer (score 27):

Follow these steps:

- In Xcode move to *Breakpoint navigator* (use `command+8` in Xcode 11)
- Click on the + option at the left bottom of the navigator and select Exception breakpoint.

[image: Exception Breakpoint]

- An exception breakpoint will be immediately added to the Breakpoint list
  in the Breakpoint navigator
- you can then edit additional Breakpoint Setting's as shown below.

[image: Breakpoint settings]